# Einstein Vision: Bad Request when I send base64 data to predict API

Tags: rest-api, node.js, einstein

I am trying to replicate a cURL request in post request in nodejs.

**The cURL:**

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN>" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "sampleBase64Content=/9j/4AAQSkZ..." -F "modelId=YCQ4ZACEPJFGXZNRA6ERF3GL5E" https://api.einstein.ai/v2/vision/predict
```

**The REST request in nodejs**

```
var option = {
    url: 'https://api.einstein.ai/v2/vision/predict',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer '+data["access_token"],
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    },
    body: 'sampleBase64Content='+imgFile.data.toString('base64')+'&modelId='+modelId
}

request.post(option, function(err, resp, bdy){
    res.send('<span>'+bdy+'</span>');
});
```

Here, `imgFile.data` is in buffer format. The response always says bad request. The documentation to the API is [here](https://metamind.readme.io/docs/prediction-with-image-base64-string).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The -F in cURL represents form-data, so I had to modify my request as follows, and it worked fine:

```
var formData = {
    modelId: modelId,
    sampleBase64Content: imgFIle.data.toString('base64')
}
var option = {
    url: 'https://api.einstein.ai/v2/vision/predict',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer '+data["access_token"],
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    },
    formData: formData
}

request.post(option, function(err, resp, bdy){
    res.send('<span>'+bdy+'</span>');
});
```